# Making your application as little (disk usage) as possible. Is it okay to put the PNG to one Drawable Folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have see lots of drawable folder. Drawable-hdpi, mdpi to xxhdpi. Is it okay to put my images to one folder only? If I put it on the drawable-mdpi, would android still get it if your screen is xxhdpi or below mdpi?

thanks

Comment: It would take maybe 30 seconds to see for yourself. Voting to close.

Comment: huh how? The ic_launcher is being found on all the folder.

Comment: you're asking if android would still get the drawables if everything is in one drawable folder. move everything there (sans duplicates -- just delete those) and test it out on your xxhdpi device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

- Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities

By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.

The last sentence explains well

Comment: Ah, so the best thing is to place icons on all the folder. Thank saving disk. :)

Comment: its not like that you put the same icon with different resolution in appropriate folder

Comment: That is what I am thinking putting the same icon with different resolution on the folder.. So this is not it?